# Fatal error: Class 'MinecraftPing' not found

Tags: php, minecraft

**Update: I have fixed it!**

This is a php script to ping a minecraft server.
You can find the code here: http://snippi.com/s/o2awm6x

I am getting the error:

> Fatal error: Class 'MinecraftPing' not found in /var/www/html/multicraft/MinecraftServerPing.php on line 21

How do I resolve this issue? I have been trying to fix this, nothing seems to work!

In the beginning I was getting this:

> Notice: Constant MQ_SERVER_ADDR already defined in /var/www/html/multicraft/MinecraftServerPing.php on line 3 Notice: Constant MQ_SERVER_PORT already defined in /var/www/html/multicraft/MinecraftServerPing.php on line 4 Notice: Constant MQ_TIMEOUT already defined in /var/www/html/multicraft/MinecraftServerPing.php on line 5 Notice: Constant MQ_SERVER_ADDR already defined in /var/www/html/multicraft/MinecraftServerPing.php on line 3 Notice: Constant MQ_SERVER_PORT already defined in /var/www/html/multicraft/MinecraftServerPing.php on line 4 Notice: Constant MQ_TIMEOUT

I fixed this by replacing the

> require

with

> require_once

Comment: The class is as far as I can tell also called [`MinecraftServerPing`](https://github.com/jamietech/MinecraftServerPing), not `MinecraftPing`. Also, renaming your file to not have the same name as the file you're trying to include is probably a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either MinecraftPing does not exist (as a class), either you are including the wrong files.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
include(__DIR__ . '/MinecraftServerPing.php');
```

instead of 
    require_once **DIR** . '/MinecraftServerPing.php';
13.

Comment: Wait I think I know what the problem is. I'll tell you what comes up.

Comment: Actually, it could be that its declared wrong, in $Query = new MinecraftServerPing( MQ_SERVER_ADDR, MQ_SERVER_PORT, MQ_TIMEOUT ); change it to $Query = new MinecraftPing( MQ_SERVER_ADDR, MQ_SERVER_PORT, MQ_TIMEOUT );

Comment: It didn't have anything to do with it. It was my own stupid mistake xD The file was missing :/

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a inconsistency here. Let me try to explain in a simple way:
You have a file named `MinecraftServerPing.php` (the one you have posted here), but you also try to include a file with the same name on line 12:

`require_once __DIR__ . '/MinecraftServerPing.php';`

Either you have the class declared in another file or you have accidentally replaced the file named `MinecraftServerPing.php` in which `MinecraftPing` class was declared, with the code you posted.